# Magento2: Received unknown parameter: cross_border_classification error in Stripe

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, stripe

I am using Magento ver. 2.3.1

I have installed the Stripe payment method and installed the supportive php library.

Configured with test account.

I am testing the stripe payment method with test mode and I am getting below error:-

```
Received unknown parameter: cross_border_classification
```

[image]
If any one have idea about it please help me Thanks

Comment: where above error comes?

Comment: I have updated the screenshot in my question please review that

Comment: If you search for "cross_border_classification" in the code, which file is that included in?

Comment: nothing is find in code like this

Comment: cross_border_classification is an old/depreciated beta API parameter for India exports, can you check the API requests from your Stripe logs to see if you are passing that parameter anywhere?